# How to map the eigenvectors of a superoperator into the corresponding operators?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, vectors, linear-algebra

The set of linear operators acting on a $d$ dimensional Hilbert space, $H$ form a  vector space, called operator space $\mathcal{L}(H)$. Elements of operator space are $d \times d$ matrices. Now the set of linear operators on the operator space, $\mathcal{L}(\mathcal{L}(H))$ form another vector space of dimension $d^4$. Elements of this space are called superoperators. Superoperators are $d^2 \times d^2$ matrices. Their eigenvectors form independent directions in the operator space and should form a complete basis if full rank.

My question is, how do I map these eigenvectors which are $d^2 \times 1$ column vectors to $d \times d$ matrices? (Since Operator space is a space of $d\times d$ matrices. Intuitively, there is a correspondence.)

Comment: An eigenvector of a superoperator is a linear operator (a $d\times d$ matrix)

Comment: Superoperator is a $d^2 \times d^2$ matrix. When you find eigenvectors, you get $d^2 \times 1$ column vectors. How to transform them to $d \times d$ matrices?

Answer (score 2):

A super-operator is a linear operator on $\mathcal L(\mathcal H)$. Its eigenvectors are elements of $\mathcal L(H)$. If you want to use matrix algebra, you have to pick a basis for $\mathcal L(H)$, compute the matrix of the superoperator *in this basis*, then diagonalise it. The $d^2\times 1$ eigenvectors you find actually represent elements of $\mathcal L(H)$ *using the basis you chose earlier*.